# Intelli J removes imports after code is uncommented

Tags: import, intellij-idea

I commented some code, and IntelliJ removed the imports automatically. All this was good. But then, I uncommented the code, and these imports are not added automatically. Is there some setting I am missing?

I have checked all options to optimize imports under Editor -> Auto Import

Answer (score 0):

Press `alt-enter` and select the imports you want. It may be ambiguous which imports you want to use for the uncommented code.